# How to separate events using jquery input type file filter

Tags: jquery, html, file, input

I made a filter for input type file. It works on change function. There is 2 events: ok and error and 2 messages.

Problem is that after reloading(or loading anytime) page value of input is empty, but function `onchange` works, and give me error message in frontend(because there is no filter access for empty value).

I want to display third message, if value is empty, but suddenly my function doesn't want to work.

**UPDATE**

And doesn't work `.remove` fonction. I made it, if person try several times to choose a file, than it get 1 message, instead messages = times he try.

So code

```
(function($) {
    $('#resume').on('change', function() {
        var err = "error-upload";
        var ok = "upload-ok";
        var ext = $('#resume').val().split(".").pop().toLowerCase();
        if ($.inArray(ext, ["doc", "pdf", 'docx', "jpeg", "jpg", "png"]) == -1) {
            $(".error-upload-wrap").remove(".error-upload");
            $(".error-upload-wrap").remove(".upload-ok");
            $(".error-upload-wrap").append("<div class=" + err + ">Error</div>")
            // false 
        } else {
            $(".error-upload-wrap").remove(".upload-ok");
            $(".error-upload-wrap").remove(".error-upload");
            $(".error-upload-wrap").append("<div class=" + ok + ">Ok</div>");
            // true
        }
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Help me please!

```js
(function($) {
  $('#resume').on('change', function() {
    var err = "error-upload";
    var ok = "upload-ok";
    var ext = $('#resume').val().split(".").pop().toLowerCase();
    if ($.inArray(ext, ["doc", "pdf", 'docx', "jpeg", "jpg", "png"]) == -1) {
      $(".error-upload-wrap").remove(".error-upload");
      $(".error-upload-wrap").remove(".upload-ok");
      $(".error-upload-wrap").append("<div class=" + err + ">Вы загрузили файл в неправильном формате <strong>." + ext + "</strong>! Допустимые форматы: .jpeg, .png, .jpg, .pdf, .doc, .docx</div>")

      // false 
    } else {
      $(".error-upload-wrap").remove(".upload-ok");
      $(".error-upload-wrap").remove(".error-upload");
      $(".error-upload-wrap").append("<div class=" + ok + ">Вы загрузили файл в правильном формате!</div>");
      // true
    }
  });
})(jQuery);
```

```css
#check_link {
  border: none;
  background-color: #008600;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  border-radius: 0;
  text-decoration: none;
  float: right;
  margin-left: 15px;
  font-size: 13px !important;
  line-height: 25px !important;
  padding: 0 40px !important;
  color: #fff;
}
.error-upload {
  background-color: #f2dede;
  border-color: #ebccd1;
}
.upload-ok {
  background-color: #dff0d8;
  border-color: #d6e9c6;
}
.error-upload-wrap div {
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  font-size: 13px;
  color: #767676;
  padding: 15px;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 60px !important;
  line-height: 24px;
  margin-bottom: 20px !important;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.upload-ok:before {
  content: "\f00c";
}
.error-upload:before {
  content: "\f00d";
}
.error-upload-wrap div:before {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 25px;
  margin-top: -11px;
  line-height: 1;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-family: FontAwesome;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="file" class="input-text addon" multiple="multiple" id="resume" />
<div class="error-upload-wrap"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why dont you just check if the value is empty inside the onchange event. Like below.

```
    (function($) {
    $('#resume').on('change', function() {
      if(!$.trim($(this).val()) == ''){ // check if input value is not empty
        var err = "error-upload";
        var ok = "upload-ok";
        var ext = $('#resume').val().split(".").pop().toLowerCase();
        if ($.inArray(ext, ["doc", "pdf", 'docx', "jpeg", "jpg", "png"]) == -1) {
            $(".error-upload-wrap").remove(".error-upload");
            $(".error-upload-wrap").remove(".upload-ok");
            $(".error-upload-wrap").append("<div class=" + err + ">Error</div>")
            // false 
        } else {
            $(".error-upload-wrap").remove(".upload-ok");
            $(".error-upload-wrap").remove(".error-upload");
            $(".error-upload-wrap").append("<div class=" + ok + ">Ok</div>");
            // true
        }
      }
      else{ // if its empty
        //do your stuff as the input value is empty.
      }
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Thanks for Rejith R Krishnan and Reddy! Great!

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you need to use this because

`$('selector1')` selects elements with `selector1`. Then `remove('selector2')` removes the elements in the selected by `selector1` which also has `selector2`.

> A selector expression that filters the set of matched elements to be removed.

```
$(".error-upload-wrap .error-upload").remove();
$(".error-upload-wrap .upload-ok").remove();
```

**See the demo below.**

```js
(function($) {
  $('#resume').on('change', function() {
    var err = "error-upload";
    var ok = "upload-ok";
    var ext = $('#resume').val().split(".").pop().toLowerCase();
    if ($.inArray(ext, ["doc", "pdf", 'docx', "jpeg", "jpg", "png"]) == -1) {
      $(".error-upload-wrap .error-upload").remove();
      $(".error-upload-wrap .upload-ok").remove();
      $(".error-upload-wrap").append("<div class=" + err + ">Вы загрузили файл в неправильном формате <strong>." + ext + "</strong>! Допустимые форматы: .jpeg, .png, .jpg, .pdf, .doc, .docx</div>")
      // false 
    } else {
      $(".error-upload-wrap .upload-ok").remove();
      $(".error-upload-wrap .error-upload").remove();
      $(".error-upload-wrap").append("<div class=" + ok + ">Вы загрузили файл в правильном формате!</div>");
      // true
    }
  });
})(jQuery);
```

```css
#check_link {
  border: none;
  background-color: #008600;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  border-radius: 0;
  text-decoration: none;
  float: right;
  margin-left: 15px;
  font-size: 13px !important;
  line-height: 25px !important;
  padding: 0 40px !important;
  color: #fff;
}
.error-upload {
  background-color: #f2dede;
  border-color: #ebccd1;
}
.upload-ok {
  background-color: #dff0d8;
  border-color: #d6e9c6;
}
.error-upload-wrap div {
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  font-size: 13px;
  color: #767676;
  padding: 15px;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 60px !important;
  line-height: 24px;
  margin-bottom: 20px !important;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.upload-ok:before {
  content: "\f00c";
}
.error-upload:before {
  content: "\f00d";
}
.error-upload-wrap div:before {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 25px;
  margin-top: -11px;
  line-height: 1;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-family: FontAwesome;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="file" class="input-text addon" multiple="multiple" id="resume" />
<div class="error-upload-wrap"></div>
```

Comment: Works great! But my problem is in that also, that after reloading i get error message on my site, but in snippet above it works fine, empty value = empty message

Comment: @Александр Not sure I understand what you are saying.

Comment: So if it hard to fix i want to display third message , that removed error of empty value first time page loaded.

Comment: http://www.ok-interiordesign.ru/shop/tovar/eskiz-planirovki/    - on this page you will see, that in error message value is empty (after point "." there is no format)

Comment: How to display third message if is empty?

Comment: @Александр give css `display:none` on load.

Comment: @Александр You can check that like this `else if($('#resume').val() == ''){}`

Comment: Thanks for Rejith R Krishnan and Reddy! Great!

Answer (score 1):

You have to check if the element to be removed is actually available in the DOM:

```
$('#resume').on('change', function() {
    var err = "error-upload";
    var ok = "upload-ok";
    var ext = $('#resume').val().split(".").pop().toLowerCase();
    if ($.inArray(ext, ["doc", "pdf", 'docx', "jpeg", "jpg", "png"]) == -1) {
        $(".error-upload-wrap").append("<div class='" + err + "'>Error</div>")
        // false 
    } else {
        $(".error-upload-wrap").append("<div class='" + ok + "'>Ok</div>");
        // true
    }

    if($('.'+err).length || $('.'+ok).length){
       $(".error-upload-wrap").remove(".error-upload, .upload-ok");
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks Jai! It's almost usefull